# Kivy TextInput and Fonts

Tags: android, python, fonts, textinput, kivy

the code in question

```
txt = TextInput(text='%s'%default, multiline=False, size_hint=(0.5,1))
txt.font_name = gAssets + "FreeSans.ttf"
Txt.font_size = 14
```

If I comment out the font_name attribute the text in the input lines up about right. (still sits a little bit high in the box but workable)

[image: Normal alignment (uses DroidSans.ttf)] (using the normal TextInput with the default font (DroidSans.ttf))

However once I uncomment the line that sets it to FreeSans.ttf (larger character set) It now sits way to high in the text field

[image: Kivy TextInput with FreeSans] (using normal TextInput with FreeSans.ttf)

I am using kivy 1.3 and have been unsuccessful at getting the padding attribute to work(however I would be happy to use it if someone could demonstrate how to use it with a TextInput.)

Comment: For a start, if you're really using kivy 1.3 why not upgrade to the current stable version (1.7)? There have been many changes since 1.3, including affecting TextInput.

Comment: http://wstaw.org/m/2013/09/07/snapshot104.png that's using the latest master. It should also work with the latest stable 1.7.2.

Comment: do you know how you can set the padding outside of the .kv file? if you do and post it as an answer Ill accept it.  as to why we are using 1.3 thats a good question, I'll inquire about the possibility of upgrading to latest

Comment: textinput_instance.padding = ('2dp', '2dp')

Comment: awesome thanks :) I figured it out once Nykakin answered ... I was trying to give ints to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alter padding inside your code using [VariableListPropery](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.VariableListProperty). Example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.properties import  VariableListProperty

class MyTextInput(TextInput):
    padding =  VariableListProperty(['24dp', '48dp'])

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyTextInput(text='This is an example text', multiline=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

This code requires 1.7 version, as noted in [documentation of the widget](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html). I recommend uprgrading as I don't even see any API archive anywhere to check how it was setted before.

Comment: yeah VariableListsPRoperty was introduced in 1.7   I cant seem to find anything on how to achieve it in 1.3 (I'll still accept your answer)